iOS - How to test the enterprise application using simulator
I am working on building iOS application for Enterprise users and generated the build using Enterprise certificate and profile.
Before sharing it with users, I would like to test it on my iOS simulator.
What I have tried

Selected Product -> Archive -> Distribute
Selected "None" for thinning apps option.
Selected the corresponding profile
Select Export option

I am able to see the exported ipa along with supporting files(including .plist).

Uploaded .ipa, .plist and other files into the server location.
Opened the link from Safari browser.
It shows a popup to download but download is stuck for long time.

Please help me understanding the steps to be followed to simula

You can't download an archive build onto a simulator. You can create simulator builds directly in Xcode and run them.  To test an archive build you will need a real device.

Okay. When trying from one of the devices by my colleague. it is getting installed but when launching, it is closed automatically. Please advice on this.

I don't know. It could be different things. Have they trusted the enterprise developer profile in settings->general? Have you actually signed the app correctly? Is it crashing?
